# How can I stop less from storing history?

Tags: less

Every time I search for a term in `less`, it stores my search in the file `.lesshst`.  How can I stop this behavior?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Open a terminal and create a file `.lesskey`, in your home folder and append the following to it:

```
#env
LESSHISTSIZE=0
```

If you already have the file `.lesshst` in your home folder, then delete it and type the command

```
lesskey
```

You shouldn't get any errors here. This will not store any history of `less` from now on, until you change the `.lesskey` file.

From [the man page of less](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?less):

> ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES
>
> ```
>    Environment variables may be specified either in the system environment
>    as usual, or in a lesskey  (1)  file.   If  environment  variables  are
>    defined  in  more  than one place, variables defined in a local lesskey
>    file take precedence over variables defined in the system  environment,
>    which take precedence over variables defined in the system-wide lesskey
>    file.
> ```
>
> LESSHISTSIZE
>
> ```
>           The maximum number of commands to save in the history file.  The
>           default is 100.
> ```

**EDIT:**

From the comments, I found a better way to prevent having a history file for less.

In the `.lesskey` file in the home folder, append this:

```
LESSHISTFILE=-
```

or

```
LESSHISTFILE=/dev/null
```

If you put this in your `~/.bashrc` file, this will work, but will have a lower precedence if you have other values in your `.lesskey` file for the same variables.

You may want to have a look at this:

- [How to make `less` more friendly](http://ascending.wordpress.com/2011/02/11/unix-tip-make-less-more-friendly/)

Comment: @InkBlend Did you use export?  I neuter less in my .bashrc with: "export LESSHISTFILE=/dev/null"

Comment: Perhaps @Jobin could add the .bashrc + export to his answer. I think he deserves the credit for a good answer.

Comment: Great. Get rid of the `.lesshst` file and add a `.lesskey` file instead. Set environment variable to `LESSSECURE=1` and it won't use lesskey file or less history file. Or just compile it with the secure option and you don't have to have the environment variable either.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
export LESSHISTFILE=-
```

To verify, you can now start a new shell, delete the `~/.lesshist` file, and then start using `less`. It should not create a new `~/.lesshist` file again.

---

Note that the `export` is important. If you leave it out, the `LESSHISTFILE` variable appears to be set (`echo $LESSHISTFILE` will output `-`), but [it will not be passed to `less`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/107853/29509).

Answer (score 0):

This is basically a bash trick incorporating the `LESSHISTFILE` override via command prefix environment manipulation.

```
history | LESSHISTFILE=/dev/null less
```

What this does is pipe the output of the `history` command into `less` while using a command prefix to manipulate the environment exposed to the `less` command.

This is described in the [bash reference](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Environment) as:

> The environment for any simple command or function may be augmented temporarily by prefixing it with parameter assignments, as described in Shell Parameters. These assignment statements affect only the environment seen by that command.

More about that *specific* use at https://stackoverflow.com/a/52208927/117471